# Swagger annotation does not produce expected result

Tags: java, spring, annotations, swagger

My team is using swagger annotation 1.5.14 to generate the swagger file for the documentation, when we define a string property with ApiModelProperty and example:

```
@ApiModelProperty(example="484799")
private String accountNumber;
```

This generates the output:

```
"accountNumber": 484799
```

Is it possible to make it generate the account number with example value double quoted:

```
"accountNumber": "484799"
```

Since it will be easier to tell between string value and number value when look at the example.

Following are we have tried so far:

1. put the escape character for double quote (example = "\"484799\"")
2. use dataType = "java.lang.String" with example parameter
3. Leave extra space in the example value.

My environment: Java 1.8, swagger annotation 1.5.14, swagger 2

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this about SpringFox or is there another Swagger implementation?

Comment: @pavel, It could be either one, if the fix is done in springfox, it could be something applies globally for all the case which string type with digits only. if there is swagger implementation, then i need to apply the fix case by case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the cause for this issue, it is in the Springfox library, the class Swagger2JacksonModule, there is a method checking based on the value:

```
 private boolean isNotJsonString(final String value) throws IOException {
    // strictly speaking, should also test for equals("null") since {"example": null} would be valid JSON
    // but swagger2 does not support null values
    // and an example value of "null" probably does not make much sense anyway
    return value.startsWith("{")                              // object
        || value.startsWith("[")                          // array
        || "true".equals(value)                           // true
        || "false".equals(value)                          // false
        || JSON_NUMBER_PATTERN.matcher(value).matches();  // number
  }
```

This checks the value only but ignores the dataType declared on the annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'dataType' element property in @ApiModelProperty.

```
@ApiModelProperty(datatype= "String", example="484799")
private String accountNumber;
```

or

```
@ApiModelProperty(datatype= "java.lang.String", example="484799")
private String accountNumber;
```

If you are using Swagger2, then @Schema is option.
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#schema

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use `String.format()` something in a similar fashion below.

```
String example="484799"
private String accountNumber = String.format("%s", example)
```

Comment: that would not be ideal, i still want it to be part of annotation but not as a value of the variable.